# Apple reject flutter app for Guideline 4.2 - Design - Minimum Functionality

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store

My **Flutter** app was published to google play 2 years ago, now trying to publish it to the apple store but they keep rejecting it for more than a month with this reply

> Guideline 4.2 - Design - Minimum Functionality
>
> We found that the usefulness of your app is limited by the minimal
> amount of content or features it includes.
>
> Next Steps
>
> We encourage you to review your app concept and incorporate different
> content and features that are in compliance with the App Store Review
> Guidelines.
>
> We understand that there are no hard and fast rules to define useful
> or entertaining, but Apple and Apple customers expect apps to provide
> a really great user experience. Apps should provide valuable utility
> or entertainment, draw people in by offering compelling capabilities
> or content, or enable people to do something they couldn't do before
> or in a way they couldn't do it before. iOS App 0.4.61App Version
> Rejection Reasons:
> 4.2.0 Design: Minimum Functionality

I have tried everything:

- Asked for screenshots of the issues they need me to fix so I can fix them as soon as possible.
  **(I got screenshots showing my app working with its features, Nothing wrong with it, Everything is working, with no design errors nothing can be the reason for rejection, All I got is)**
- I explained the benefit of the app and how it can help **(I got the same rejection reason)**
- I explained App content one by one with the reason for adding it **(I got the same rejection reason)**
- I applied for an appeal
  **(I got this reply )**

> The App Review Board determined that the original rejection feedback
> was valid. Your app does not comply with:
>
> Guideline 4.2 - Design - Minimum Functionality

This is the TestFlight public link if anyone can test the app and tell me what's wrong with it that makes Apple keep rejecting it?

https://testflight.apple.com/join/KTWUJAST

Please if someone can help I'm so desperate here.

Comment: I tried the testflight build and I'm afraid I have to agree with Apple.  The app feels like a repackaged web site. It doesn't work without an internet connection, so it doesn't even offer benefits of working offline. Starting the app without internet just leaves you sitting at a white screen. The bus map just opened a Google map in a modal web view.  This app will never be approved in its current state.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your comment and testing the app, I really appreciate it, for internet point, the app gets all info from the server so if I allow it to open without the internet there isn't anything to display, so Apple or Google will not approve to publish it, for (The bus map) thanks for your feedback I fixed it to open with any available map app on the device, I have updated TestFlight if you can test it again for me, it'll be kind from you, Please tell me if there is anything else I need to fix.

Comment: @Paulw11 "It doesn't work without an internet connection" - that's a bullshit reason. Gazzilion apps work only with internet nowadays. Try tweeting something without network.

Comment: Of course apps that need the internet, need the internet. I wasn't saying that all apps should be able to operate without the internet. In this case Apple rejected the app for not having enough utility. I was pointing out that the app could have more utility if it worked while offline as an example.  Also, not having full functionality while offline is one thing, but simply hanging at a white screen is not acceptable; it will lead to rejection by Apple.

Answer (score -1):

You have probably already tried this so if you have just disregard. But, for me, canceling my review submission and then resubmitting a new build for review has worked. Sometimes I just have had bad luck with certain reviewers…

Comment: How to do that? I (Cancel Submission) and made a new one but I think I still have the same reviewer, the same reply with the same behaviour, Could you help?